# Replacing a class content with an integer value not working in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a class that has some numeric content displayed. I want to retrieve it and increment its value each time a specific action is taken.

```
<div class="abc">
  <span class="a">1</span>    
</div>

var count = parseInt(($this.parents('.abc').find('.a').text())); 
var count++;
```

The above code works correctly but I want the previous value to be replaced with the incremented one but it is not working.

```
$this.parents('.abc').find('.a').text(count);  //not working
$this.parents('.abc').find('.a').val(count);  //also not working
```

Comment: the target html markup

Comment: Your target html seems funny, could you post your html code?

Comment: I think you can just increment the value directly in your first line. Try `$('.vote-count-post')[0].innerText++` on this page

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me:

HTML:

```
<div class="abc">
    <div class="a">1</div>    
</div>
```

JS:

```
var count = parseInt($('.abc').find('.a').text()); 
count++;

$('.abc').find('.a').text(count);
```

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/R8hww/2/

Comment: You should post this a comment not as an answer. Additionally you modified the source code without knowing the goals of the asker.

Comment: Better to use `text()` instead of `html()`, it will be slightly faster.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need jQuery for this. Try something like:

`document.querySelector('.abc .a').innerText++`

OR

`$('.abc .a')[0].innerText++`

OR

`$this.parents('.abc').find('.a').text(parseInt($this.parents('.abc').find('.a').text())+1)`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/232Fj/5/)